# Spark ElasticSearch Configuration - Reading Elastic Search from Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, hadoop

I am trying to read data from ElasticSearch via Spark Scala. I see lot of post addressing this question, i have tried all the options they have mentioned in various posts but seems nothing is working for me

```
JAR Used - elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.8.jar (Used elasticsearch-spark-5.6.8.jar too without any success)
Elastic Search Version - 5.6.8
Spark - 2.3.0
Scala - 2.11
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

import org.elasticsearch.spark._ 

val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("elasticSpark").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

val reader = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.index.auto.create", "true").option("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").option("es.port", "9200").option("es.nodes", "xxxxxxxxx").option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true").option("es.net.http.auth.user","xxxxxx").option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "xxxxxxxx")

val read = reader.load("index/type")

Error:
ERROR rest.NetworkClient: Node [xxxxxxxxx:9200] failed (The server xxxxxxxxxxxxx failed to respond); no other nodes left - aborting...
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:294)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.SchemaUtils$.discoverMappingAndGeoFields(SchemaUtils.scala:98)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.SchemaUtils$.discoverMapping(SchemaUtils.scala:91)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.lazySchema$lzycompute(DefaultSource.scala:129)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.lazySchema(DefaultSource.scala:129)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:133)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation$$anonfun$schema$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:133)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.ElasticsearchRelation.schema(DefaultSource.scala:133)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:432)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
  ... 53 elided
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopNoNodesLeftException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[xxxxxxxxxxx:9200]]
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.NetworkClient.execute(NetworkClient.java:149)
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:461)
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:425)
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:429)
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:155)
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.remoteEsVersion(RestClient.java:655)
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:287)
  ... 65 more
```

Apart from this I have also tried below properties without any success:

```
option("es.net.ssl.cert.allow.self.signed", "true")
option("es.net.ssl.truststore.location", "<path for elasticsearch cert file>")
option("es.net.ssl.truststore.pass", "xxxxxx")
```

Please note elasticsearch node is within Unix edge node and is http://xxxxxx:9200 (mentioning it just in case if that makes any difference with the code)

What I am missing here? Any other properties? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Use below Jar which support spark 2+ version instead  of Elastic-Hadoop or Elastic-Spark jar.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11/5.6.8